# How to setup an alarm on AWS DynamoDB for failed INSERT attempt

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, aws-iot-core

I am using AWS IoT Core to process incoming MQTT messages and sending them to a DynamoDB table.

I want to set an alarm to notify me using SNS if data being sent failed to insert into the DynamoDB Table.

I have an SNS topic setup and working, but I can't see a way in the Alarms tab of DynamoDB to alert for failed a INSERT.

Ideally I'd like to get an alert and see the data that couldn't be inserted.

Answer (score 0):

There is no mechanism in DynamoDB to audit for this event as CloudTrail currently does not support data plane logging for DynamoDB.

I am not familiar with AWS IoT Core, but can you add code to catch the failure of a write where it kicks an entry in SNS for you?

Comment: I have an Error handling rule set up pointed towards a SNS topic. But when I tested it with invalid data I didn't receive an alert, so I'm guessing it won't catch failed Inserts